# How to fit Weibull distribution using “MME” method and find the estimates in R

Tags: r, distribution, weibull

I am trying to fit a Weibull distribution in R using MME method and find the estimates. Below is the code used to fit the weibull distribution in R from the fitdistrplus and actuar package.

```
a <- rweibull(100, 10,1)
weibul_mme <- mmedist(a, "weibull", order = 1:2)
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Error in mmedist(a, "weibull", order = 1:2) : 
  the empirical moment function must be defined
```

It would be helpful if anyone can tell me what mistake I am making or provide some reading material for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R code below, Microsoft R Open 3.5.3 x64, Win 10

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)

x <- rweibull(1000, 10,1)

memp <- function(x, order) mean(x^order)

weibul_mme <- mmedist(x, "weibull", order = 1:2, memp=memp)
fit.weibull<- fitdist(x, "weibull", method = "mme", order=c(1, 2), memp=memp, lower = c(0, 0))

print(weibul_mme)
print(fit.weibull)

plot(fit.weibull, demp=TRUE)
```

produced reasonable fit using MME method

[image]

Comment: The only thing which I did not understand in the above code is `memp <- function(x, order) mean(x^order)`. Could you kindly explain what this code does?

Comment: @PrasadDalvi We declare function which is used to compute moments from sampled (empirical) data, this is why it is called `memp`. It corresponds to standard definition of moments as E[X^n], see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics) for details. F.e. for mean value function would be called with order parameter of 1, and you'll get back mean value of empirical (sampled) data. For second order parameter order would be equal to 2, and you'll get back mean of squared values and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to fit Weibull distribution with the fast and efficient Le Cam one-step estimation procedure using the `onestep` command in the `OneStep` package.

```
library(OneStep)
library(actual)

set.seed(2023)
x <- rweibull(100, 10,1)
onestep(x,"weibull")

Parameters:
        estimate
shape 10.1071280
scale  0.9845747
```